# Why doesn’t autocorrect software like “unauthorises”?

Tags: is-it-a-word, word-formation

I was writing some documentation and trying to write a sentence that ran like this:

> It then **unauthorises** the transaction.

I soon realised this wasn't a word, and it kept correcting this to *unauthorised*.

This got me to wondering: Why is *authorises* a word but not *unauthorises*?

Comment: From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deauthorize): << **deauthorize** /  de-authorise:
Etymology
de- +‎ authorize.
... 

(transitive) To revoke permission, sanction or consent.>> While _un_- usually just implies 'without, not',  _de_- usually indicates the removal of something.

Comment: The opposite of *allow* is *deny*.

Comment: @tchrist: I assume whenever ***unauthorise*** is "validly" used as an "active" verb (as opposed to adjectival past participle in *an unauthorised transaction*), the meaning would always be *to **retract** [a previously-issued authorisation]*. Which is actually a meaningful action, so it's not like *an unlit fire* (where I'm far from convinced it would ever be credible to *unlight the fire* - you're have to use a completely different verb such as *douse* or *put out*).

Comment: Newer putt mush thrust an shell chick sifter.  Its manly they're do warm yon it yon serious lye misty pee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous adjectives (*unauthorized*, *unbroken*, *uncooked*, etc.) exist as negative forms of positive adjectives (*authorized*, *broken*, *cooked*, etc.) by the simple prefixing of *un-* to the positive adjective to indicate that the positive action has not occurred.

The positive action implied by each adjective is itself obviously derived from a verb form (*authorize*, *break*, *cook*, etc.). But it does not follow that the underlying verb makes sense in negated form in every case: *untie* and *unwind* work as reverse processes for *tie* and *wind*, but in practical terms it makes no sense to speak of trying to unbreak an egg or uncook a casserole. (Note that some such verbs don't respond well to the counteracting/negating prefix *de-* either, as in *debreak* and *decook*.)

*Authorize* falls into this latter group of verbs that don't have a simple negative form based on the prefix *un-*. To express the negative in this instance, most speakers and writers would probably use a phrase such as "rescind authorization" or "revoke authorization," although—as Edwin Ashworth suggests in a comment above—*deauthorize* may be acceptable in some settings.

Comment: Some adjectives ending in *‑ed* have their origin not in verbs but in nouns.  Neither *cultured* opinions nor *uncultured* ones have a verb behind them; similarly *horned, manicured, diseased, moneyed, bigoted,* and many more besides.

Comment: It may be a bit of a Sisyphean task to try to unbreak an egg, but it is clearly possible to unbreak my heart, say you'll love me again, undo this hurt you cause when you walked out the door and walked out of my life. One might, nonetheless, question whether it is really possible to uncry these tears I've cried so many nights…